# Reachability class not working with 3g connection

Tags: objective-c, reachability

```
-(BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}


if (![self connected]) {


    NSLog(@"Not Connected");
} else {        
    NSLog(@"Connected");

    // connected, do some internet stuff
}
```

The above code is perfectly working with Wifi.When i use 3G connectivity it is not working correctly.I do not know how to change code for 3G connectivity.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reachability is only used to detect if a system has connection to a gateway to the internet but doesn't go in-depth and check whats behind it. There a times when a LAN is reachable but there no gateway to the internet. You're have to make a actual real request to a server. Take a look at this great [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk?rq=1) on how to implement on all types of connectivity